# The ratio of factorials of sum approximation

Tags: statistics, algorithms, approximation, gamma-function, approximation-theory

I am wondering if the following can be approximated: 
$$\frac{(k+n)!}{(kN+c+n)!}$$
where all the variables in the above are positive integers. Anyway, I want to separate $c$ from the above so that we can write it as $f(k,n,N).f(c)$ where the '.' is any mathematical operation.

Comment: If $kN+n$ is much larger than $c$ then $(kN + n + c)! \approx (kN + n + 1)^c (kN + n)!$.

Comment: @Gary it's still $f(n,c,k,N)$

Comment: If $n$ is much larger than the others then $\frac{{(k + n)!}}{{(kN + c + n)!}} \approx \frac{{(k + n)!}}{{n^{kN + c} n!}} \approx \frac{{n^k }}{{n^{kN + c} }} = n^{k(1 - N) - c} $. I do not think there is a way to have the dependence on $c$ completely separated.

Comment: $\log\left( (kN + n + 1)^c (kN + n)!\right) = c\log(kN + n + 1)+\log((kN + n)!)$ which is still not separation, though some might think it is closer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approximation is obtained by the Stirling formula
$$
n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}n^ne^{-n}\qquad n\rightarrow\infty.
$$
In your case, we assume $(n+k)\rightarrow\infty$ and this is enforced in $kN+n$ at the denominator. Then, one has
$$
\frac{(n+k)!}{(kN+n+c)!}\approx\sqrt{\frac{n+k}{kN+k+c}}\frac{(n+k)^{n+k}}{(kN+n+c)^{kN+n+c}}e^{(N-1)k+c}.
$$
Now,
$$
(kN+n+c)^{kN+n+c}=e^{(kN+n+c)\ln(kN+n+c)}\approx e^{(kN+n)\ln(kN+n)}\left[1+(\ln(kN+n)+1)c\right],
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{kN+n+c}}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{kN+n}}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{kN+n}c\right)
$$
This yields,
$$
\frac{(n+k)!}{(kN+n+c)!}\approx\sqrt{\frac{n+k}{kN+k}}\frac{(n+k)^{n+k}}{(kN+n)^{kN+n}}\left[1-\left(\ln(kN+n)+1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{kN+n}\right)c\right]e^{(N-1)k+c}\approx\frac{(n+k)!}{(kN+n)!}\left[1-\left(\ln(kN+n)+1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{kN+n}\right)c\right].
$$
Even if the second term multiplying $c$ is neglected, in the considered limit, there is no way to write this exactly in the form $f(k,N,n)\cdot f(c)$.